# javascript validation on Submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

Want to use javascript validation to work when i click submit button. What happens now is even if i enter a low value the value submits. but i need to check the validation before i click submit...

This is the Javascript:

```
$(function () {
   $("#newMonoReading").on('focusout', function () {
       var str = "";

        var initialMonoReading = $('#InitialMonoReading').val();
        var newMonoReading = $('#newMonoReading').val()
        if (~~newMonoReading < ~~initialMonoReading) {
            $('#MonoErrorMessage').text("New Mono Readings must be MORE than existing");
            $('#MonoErrorMessage').show();
        } else {
            $('#MonoErrorMessage').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Now on my form, you can see the input type (Submit)

```
<div class="modal-footer">
<input type="submit" value="Submit New Readings" class="btn btn-primary">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

How do i get the JavaScript function to the submit button, so when i enter submit it wont work because i have entered a low value.

Comment: use button instead of submit

Comment: @Edrich: If you want to submit a `form`, use a submit button.

Comment: @Amberlamps you can submit button using jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function validateForm() {
   var str = "";

    var initialMonoReading = $('#InitialMonoReading').val();
    var newMonoReading = $('#newMonoReading').val();
    if (~~newMonoReading < ~~initialMonoReading) {
        $('#MonoErrorMessage').text("New Mono Readings must be MORE than existing");
        $('#MonoErrorMessage').show();
        return false;
    } else {
        $('#MonoErrorMessage').hide();
    }
}
```

This example will clear things 
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FhgQS/494/)

```
    <form onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <input type="submit"  value="Submit New Readings" class="btn btn-primary">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: A copy and paste isn't going to help someone understand. The point of having someone help you with a problem is to understand the issue in hand and learn how to fix it, not just copy/paste. Plenty of free source out there for that.

Comment: what i want is, when i click submit the readings must be higher than the existing reading. at the moment if its lower it still submits the form, but i dont want that to happen, i want the javascript error to show if the values are lower when i click submit button

Comment: @NewToJS i think it was pretty simple to understand ..anyways updated my answer to make it more clear..

Comment: @mali Please try this code and let me know .. i am sure if your code of checking initialmonoreading is correct .. it will work as you wish

Comment: You think it is because you know how to fix it. For those who haven't used this method won't understand it. Sometimes you have to be clear and explain what the source is doing rather than assume everyone has the same knowledge as you. Not trying to be awful or anything but it's true.

Comment: @NewToJS Calm down.. why are getting wockedup? I am making things clear right? let us find solution rather than getting personal..

Comment: right i have added the onSubmit, but when i click the submit button it stil submits. The error message shows, but i think the problem is, i haven't added anything to say don't continue, rather am just showing an message so either way am assuming message will still show, so how would i able not continue if it the message is shown..

Comment: I'm not getting worked up, maybe you're taking it too personal? I'm just making a valid point. Without them knowing/understanding what it is you're giving them they can't learn from it. Take it as constructive criticism.

Comment: sorry guys my fault i did assume you may no it. but i he helped me, because i now no its the onSubmit that i was missing. but now its another problem because the validation just shows/hide a message. i need an alert on submit to say the error message

Comment: @mali did the code worked .. I think the ; was missing on the second line , alert are already present on the fiddle.. try to use it according to your requirement..

Comment: its not working. when i enter a low value yes the alert shows. BUT, when i click submit it still submits the form even though the value is less. what i want is the form not to submit if there is a low value so i want the error message to show on the click of submit...

Comment: Are you trying the same thing from the fiddle .. can u update the fiddle and give the link . so that we could solve the problem

Comment: this is my full code: http://jsfiddle.net/FhgQS/497/

your js fiddle i understand, but problem is, when i click submit, it still runs and send the information to the database... but i want the error message to show on submit.

Comment: thank you this works, can you check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26972008/onsubmit-button-works-only-for-1-function?noredirect=1#comment42479866_26972008 am trying to add 2 fuctions now

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually want the validation on the `submit` button, since there are other ways to submit a form.  You actually want the validation the the form's `onsubmit` handler.

Now, that said, you haven't shown enough of your code to know where the problem is, but I can take a good guess.

Before this line:

```
$("#newMonoReading").on('focusout', function () {
```

Add this line:

```
alert($("#newMonoReading").length);
```

There is a good chance you are trying to run this code before the DOM has been rendered. If that returns `0`, you have three choices:

- Use event delegation (overkill in this case)
- Move the code inside a `$(function() {...});` block
- Load the scripts at the bottom of the page.

Comment: what i want is, when i click submit the readings must be higher than the existing reading. at the moment if its lower it still submits the form, but i dont want that to happen, i want the javascript error to show if the values are lower when i click submit button

Comment: I had a slight oops, I meant `onsubmit`' -- not `submit`. Fixed.  That will still get triggered if the user uses the `submit` button, or presses ENTER to submit the form.

Comment: this has made it worse, when i click the button, an alert appears (1). then when i click submit it doesnt work and gives error in code. i just dont want user to carry on until the message has gone

Comment: Ok.. the alert(1) means the element *does* exist -- which is what we needed to check for.  I"ll delete this answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Change the submit button to button
In this way, you will have full control of the submit. You can perform your own logic in the `validate()` function and decide whether allow the form to submit or not

```
<input type="button" onclick="validate()" value="Submit New Readings" class="btn btn-primary">
```

and your the validate function will be

```
function validate () {
   var initialMonoReading = $('#InitialMonoReading').val();
   var newMonoReading = $('#newMonoReading').val()
   if (~~newMonoReading < ~~initialMonoReading) 
  {
     alert("Value is not valid");
     return;
  }
  ///else submit
   $("yourform").submit();
});
```