# onsubmit button works only for 1 function

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 functions in javascript, but only returns one one of the error rather then both of them.

if i delete one function then other works, but if i have 2 functions it only shows one.

this is my javascript:

```
     function validateForm(event) {
    event = event || window.event || event.srcElement;
    var initialMonoReading = $('#InitialMonoReading').val();
    var newMonoReading = $('#newMonoReading').val()
    if (~~newMonoReading < ~~initialMonoReading) {
        $('#MonoErrorMessage').text("New Mono Readings must be MORE than existing");
        $('#MonoErrorMessage').show();
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        $('#MonoErrorMessage').hide();
    }
}

function validateForm(event) {
    event = event || window.event || event.srcElement;
    var InitialColourReading = $('#InitialColourReading').val();
    var newColourReading = $('#newColourReading').val()
    if (~~newColourReading < ~~InitialColourReading) {
        $('#ColourErrorMessage').text("New Colour Readings must be MORE than existing");
        $('#ColourErrorMessage').show();
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        $('#ColourErrorMessage').hide();
    }
}
```

This is my submit:

```
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "ReadingsEntry", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", onsubmit = "validateForm(event)"}))
```

This works only for the ColourErrorMessage . but ignores MonoErrorMessage. when it should show both errors....

so why is it skipping one of the functions

Comment: can u post fiddle & second why u r calling same function 2 time..

Comment: because it has diffrent id for both of them...

Comment: Please format code and post in a presentable format.

Comment: @mali : Trigger one function and inside check for if ID is matching  then show the Message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring two functions with the same name in the same scope will cause the latest one to overwrite the earlier one.

Best to do this:

```
function validateForm(event){
    validateMono(event)
    validateColor(event) //Or something to combine the results.
}

function validateMono(event) {
    event = event || window.event || event.srcElement;
    var initialMonoReading = $('#InitialMonoReading').val();
    var newMonoReading = $('#newMonoReading').val()
    if (~~newMonoReading < ~~initialMonoReading) {
        $('#MonoErrorMessage').text("New Mono Readings must be MORE than existing");
        $('#MonoErrorMessage').show();
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        $('#MonoErrorMessage').hide();
    }
}

function validateColor(event) {
    event = event || window.event || event.srcElement;
    var InitialColourReading = $('#InitialColourReading').val();
    var newColourReading = $('#newColourReading').val()
    if (~~newColourReading < ~~InitialColourReading) {
        $('#ColourErrorMessage').text("New Colour Readings must be MORE than existing");
        $('#ColourErrorMessage').show();
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        $('#ColourErrorMessage').hide();
    }
}
```

Then for the HTML:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "ReadingsEntry", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", onsubmit = "validateForm(event)"}))
```